# how to remove last node on a Circular Singly Linked List

Tags: java

I am having problem with removing the last node.  it will remove the 2nd to last instead of last.

```
public Node removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    Node temp = first.next;
    if (last.next == last) {
        first = null;
    } else {
        first.next = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = null;
    length--;
    return temp;

}
```

the "first" is the previous node to last.  When i declared it.  i pointed the last Node to the last integer and the first Node to the fourth integer.  (i have 5 integers).  if you need my entire code.  please just ask.  Thanks

Comment: Please describe better what `removeLast()` is supposed to do.  What should it be returning to the caller?

Comment: Add the definition of `first` and `last`. [mcve] would be best

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last we would need a reference to the next to last node. This way we can simply make the next to last node point to the first and update the last node to this next to last node. Java garbage collection will take care of the rest

```
public Node removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    Node temp2 = first;
    Node temp = first.next;
    while(temp.next != null) {temp2 = temp; temp = temp.next;}
    //now temp 2 should be pointing to the SECOND LAST node 
    temp2.next = first; //now the second last node points at the first 
    last = temp2; //our new last node
    /*Take care of counters and returns here*/

}
```

This code wont compile and will throws errors on a list length of 1, you will need to do some edge case checking but this should get you started

The reason why we cant just remove the last node is we need to maintain the circular property of the list

Comment: I think it would be better to just return if `isEmpty()` and shouldn't this be returning `void` instead of `Node`

Comment: @Sedrick I agree, I was just using his function defintion